# How to don't view a ?channel

Tags: php, youtube-api

How to don't a view ?channel= in my website if i'm on ?user=

Code:

https://hastebin.com/xetanogeta.xml

Comment: u can use post method... or use encode and decode in url

Answer (score 0):

This should help.
I used this for my site to select the type of call I needed to make.

```
$user = $_GET['user'];  
$youtube = $user;
$test_UCLA = $user;

strlen($user);
$user = substr($user, 0, 2);

if(($user == 'UC')&&($test_UCLA !== 'UCLA')){
    $data = file_get_contents('https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?&id='.$youtube.'&key='. $API_KEY);
}else{
    $data = file_get_contents('https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?&forUsername='.$youtube.'&key='. $API_KEY);   
}
```